# wrong view moved from recycler view to another?

Tags: android, view, android-recyclerview

I have two recycler views in my app view A and B, if you touch a card in view A it is cloned from view A to view B if you touch a card from view B it is just removed from its view, my problem is the cards in view A, no matter which one you press it will always just add the first card from view A to view B, you could press which ever one you want and it just adds the first then second and then third and then forth etc,

I show a snackbar when one is pressed, it displays some info for the card and this info is always correct,

example;

if the first card I press is 1

snackbar shows card 1 pressed, the actual card added is card 1,

if I then chose card 4

snackbar shows card 4 pressed but card added will be card 2

if I chose card 6

snackbar shows card 6 pressed but card added will be 3

so the onClick method is getting the right position but my method adding the card must be wrong and I'm not sure how to correct it maybe someone here could help,

this is my on click for the recycler view B

```
 recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new  
 RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), recyclerView,   
 new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {

            CardWriter cardWriter = cardMakerList.get(position);
            addTo(SpeakGrid.cardMakerList.size());
            Snackbar.make(view, "This card is " + 
            cardWriter.getCardEmotion() + " and it would say " +  
            cardWriter.getCardEmotion(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();

        }
```

and this is my addTo method

```
    public void addTo(int position) {
    CardWriter cardWriter = cardMakerList.get(position);
    SpeakGrid.cardMakerList.add(position, cardWriter);
    SpeakGrid.cardAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
    SpeakGrid.cardAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, 
    cardMakerList.size());

    SpeakGrid.textToSpeak.append(cardWriter.getSpeechText());
}
```

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up ditching the method and doing everything in the onclick call, that way the position was always correct so my code now looks like this

```
public void onClick(View view, int position) { //gets correct position
  CardWriter cardWriter = cardMakerList.get(position);
  SpeakGrid.cardMakerList.add(SpeakGrid.cardMakerList.size(),cardWriter);
  SpeakGrid.cardAdapter.notifyItemInserted(SpeakGrid.cardMakerList.size());
  //i update two recyclerviews
  SpeakRecyclerGrid.cardMakerList.add
  (SpeakRecyclerGrid.cardMakerList.size(),cardWriter);
  SpeakRecyclerGrid.cardAdapter.notifyItemInserted
  (SpeakGrid.cardMakerList.size());
```